# In Excel VBA, can Application.Caller.Rows.Count ever be not equal to one?

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA, can `Application.Caller.Rows.Count` ever be not equal to one?

Likewise with `Application.Caller.Columns.Count`

And what scenario would cause one of those to be not equal to 1?

Comment: Select A1:B2 and inside a `Worksheet_Change` event check if it still is one if you hit "del". Or call a sub via the immediate window (it should error out).

Comment: It can be superior to 1 if the function is entered as an array formula (Ctrl + Shift + Enter).

Comment: @FlorentB. I looked into array formulas http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/array-formulas.html  And I just tried `Function abc(a As Variant) 

MsgBox CStr(Application.Caller.Rows.Count) 

End Function`   And in a cell I did this `=abc(K4:K8-L4:L8)` with ctrl-shift-enter,  and the msgbox said "1"

Comment: @barlop, an array formula is entered is multiple cells, but executed only once for all of them. In this specific case `Application.Caller` returns the range where all the formula are entered. Looks like you tested it with only one cell.

Comment: @FlorentB. can you point me to any webpage that discusses array formulas entered in multiple cells so I can try one of those examples to see what you mean?

Comment: @barlop, [Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

Comment: @FlorentB.  do you have any example on how to write an array formula function i.e. not just using the multiplication operator?
  I've just made a question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141885/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-write-a-function-that-can-work-in-an-array-formula