# In Excel VBA, how do I write a function that can work in an array formula?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, I know  I can use an array formula on multiple cells, by selecting a range of cells of Col C, and doing =A1:10*B1:B10  Ctrl-shift-enter.

But suppose instead of the multiplication operator, I want it to be my mymult.

How would I write the mymult function?

```
Function MyMult(a As Integer, b As Integer)
  MyMult = a * b
End Function
```

What I have isn't working

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output? `(1*2)*(1*3)*(1*4)` = `24`?

Comment: Your example is inadequate since the best way to fulfill the requirements would be to put `=a1*b1` in C1 and then double-click the fill handle.

Comment: Also why are `a` and `b` declared as `Integer` when you are expecting to use them as `Range`?

Comment: There is also `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:10,B1:B10)`

Comment: @BruceWayne  You ask if my expected result is that one number, the product of them all.    No,  it's not one number.  I said this is an array formula on multiple cells. That's where you select multiple cells before doing ctrl-shift-enter

Comment: @Jeeped  I don't know what you mean by double clicking a fill handle.. The only time i've ever used a fill handle is dragging it. I don't see what double clicking it would or could do.  And also I gave the example of multiplication as an example to demonstrate the question being asked. If somebody is talking about linked lists and uses an example with 3 items in it, are you going to say their example is inadequate because it should have loads of items in it.

Comment: @ScottCraner  and this applies to Jeeped too.My example was perfectly adequate hence Florent answered it, and clearly it could do a variety of things potentially but I used the multiplication example because of its simplicity.The key concept here is array formula.And the answer doesn't just need to be applied to multiplication.That was just an example. Like if a question says how do I sum the values 1,2,3 in a linked list. The answer shouldn't be oh =1+2+3 done  Don't ignore the question The question if answered(as Florent has),demonstrates something deeper  than how to multiply numbers.

Comment: @BruceWayne You ask "Also why are a and b declared as Integer when you are expecting to use them as Range?"  <-- Well, multiplication can work on Integers too. And I wanted my function to be able to too. As florent's answer does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the arguments as variant. Then use `Application.Caller.HasArray` to check if the UDF is used as an array formula:

```
Public Function MyMult(a, b)
  If Application.Caller.HasArray Then
    Dim valsA(), valsB(), r&
    valsA = a.Value
    valsB = b.Value

    For r = LBound(valsA) To UBound(valsA)
      valsB(r, 1) = valsA(r, 1) * valsB(r, 1)
    Next

    MyMult = valsB
  Else
    MyMult = a * b
  End If
End Function
```

Note that you need to select C1:C3 before pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

Comment: Oh cool, I never knew of the `HasArray` thing. Nice thinking, I'll have to remember that.

Comment: Is there any way for an array formula to be aware of and respond to the specific row? So for example, for the multiply function to not just multiply them but to append to the result based on what row it is e.g. https://i.imgur.com/cITiW6Q.png

Comment: An array formula processes all the rows in a single call and returns the results in an array. So yes it's possible. In this example `r` is the index of the row.